# How to let some derived classes use the same method, and some other derived classes use another?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
class A{};
class X1:A{};
class X2:A{};
class Y1:X1{};
class Y2:X2{};
class Z1:X1{};
class Z2:X2{};
```

There may be more classes in the X layer like class X3:A{};...
Each X? class has two derived class Y? and Z?.
I need to add a method that all Y1...Yn instances do the same, and all Z1...Zn instances use another method implementation.
And this is a non-public method that invoked by the method in class A.
Is there an elegant way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Isn't it what method overloading is for?

Comment: Can you give any more specifics about your classes? Or the methods you are trying to use? (I don't mean what do they do, I mean, what do they need to know etc)

Comment: What class will your objects be? `Y*` and `Z*`s?

Comment: Tried to edit, but too late, so: In particular, I don't understand how an object of class `A` will know whether you want `Y` or `Z` implementation, when you call the function. Does class `A` have a variable set describing which set of inheritances you want it to follow? It seems to me this only makes sense if you're calling from child objects, at which point you're not 'invok[ing] by the method in class A'. Perhaps I'm vastly missing the point?

Comment: @vim That will cause each class of Y1...Yn will hold a copy of the same code.

Comment: @vim is talking about what I put in my initial (deleted) answer - the idea of having each Y and each Z inherit from some parentY or parentZ, I think. Then you put the implementation there, but you'll need public inheritance (hence why I deleted my answer, since you didn't want that)

Comment: @chrisb2244 In my situation, class A is a public module. we never create an object of A, Y*s and Z*s are the instantiated classes, we use virtual functions to do the work which is different in each project.

Comment: Is public inheritance then allowed, even if the function being called is private?

Comment: I'm not sure my new answer is what you're looking for, but perhaps if you comment about the bits you don't like, I can rework it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If public inheritance is acceptable, then you can define parent classes, and have pointers to these classes within your derived classes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    // A cannot be abstract - it must be able to invoke a 
    // "non-public method" whose implementation varies based on Y vs Z
    public:
    virtual void myFun()=0;
    void callMyFun(){myFun();}
};

class Y
{
public:
    void myFun(){cout<< "myFun from Y superclass" << endl;}
};

class Z
{
public:
    void myFun(){cout<< "myFun from Z superclass" << endl;}
};

class X1:public A{};
class X2:public A{};
class Y1:X1{
    Y* y;
    void myFun(){y->myFun();}
};
class Y2:public X2{
    Y* y;
    void myFun(){y->myFun();}
};
class Z1:public X1{
    Z* z;
    void myFun(){z->myFun();}
};
class Z2:public X2{
    Z* z;
    void myFun(){z->myFun();}
};

int main()
{
    Y2 myY2;
    myY2.callMyFun(); // myFun from Y superclass
}
```

Comment: That is what I want, it's gonna work if some slight changes are made. I think there is no big difference with the Delegation Pattern.

Comment: Yes -> this is my non-link answer form trying to explain the idea. Even if you are comfortable with the idea, other readers might not be

Answer (score 2):

[Delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#C.2B.2B_example_.28complex.29) pattern might answer you question

this example is a C++ version of the complex Java example above. Since C++ does not have an interface construct, a pure virtual class plays the same role. The advantages and disadvantages are largely the same as in the Java example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class I {
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
    virtual ~I() {}
};

class A : public I {
  public:
    void f() { cout << "A: doing f()" << endl; }
    void g() { cout << "A: doing g()" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "A: cleaning up." << endl; }
};

class B : public I {
  public:
    void f() { cout << "B: doing f()" << endl; }
    void g() { cout << "B: doing g()" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "B: cleaning up." << endl; }
};

class C : public I {
  public:
    // construction/destruction
    C() : i( new A() ) { }
    virtual ~C() { delete i; }

  private:
    // delegation
    I* i;

  public:
    void f() { i->f(); }
    void g() { i->g(); }

    // normal attributes
    void toA() { delete i; i = new A(); }
    void toB() { delete i; i = new B(); }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.f();   //A: doing f()
    c.g();   //A: doing g()
    c.toB(); //A: cleaning up.
    c.f();   //B: doing f()
    c.g();   //B: doing g()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [PIMPL](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) idiom. Functions implementations are encapsulated in a class which your Y*s and Z*s are delegating to.

Comment: I've no idea what's the relationship between PIMPL and my question

Comment: @pangshapeng It's funny because the answer you have accepted is what pimpl idiom actually is